# JsonFormat solution for regular Java Project enum

Tags: java, json, enums

In Java Spring project I had enum:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum ResponseStatus {

    SUCCESS                     (0,"OK"),
    SYSTEM_UNAVAILABLE          (1001, "System Unavailable"),
    SYSTEM_INTERNAL_ERROR       (1002, "System Internal Error"),
    APPLICATION_FUND_LOAN_COMPLETED (4015, "Application Fund Loan Completed");

    private int code;
    private String message;

    private ResponseStatus(int code, String message) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

I had to move this Enum to Pure Java project. Is there a JsonFormat like solution for this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own class to serialize your object:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = YourSerializer.class)
public enum ResponseStatus {...
```

This is the link for details: [more info](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums)